# Adding a drop caps to word docuemnt

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I need to format word document using C# program.
Everything is fine. But how can I insert a drop caps?
I want something like this:

[image]

I have tryied to use:

```
            Word.Range rng = doc.Range();
            rng.Font.Size=56;
```

but it is not the same as a drop caps.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Do it in word with the macro recorder running, that will show you the object model methods that are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy when you use Word's macro recorder. You need to format the range as follows:

```
var dropCap = doc.Range().Paragraphs[1].DropCap
dropCap.Position = Word.WdDropPosition.wdDropNormal  
dropCap.FontName = "+Body"
dropCap.LinesToDrop = 3
dropCap.DistanceFromText = CentimetersToPoints(0)
```

<sub>Note that I converted the code from VBA to C# manually, so there is no guarantee that it compiles like that in C#.</sub>